# StrCat is not working with Single Char String - C

Tags: c

I'm using the code below to add some "0" chars into my string, but it seems there is a problem and the program will crash. Everything seems logic but I do not know where is the problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *Ten; int i=0; Ten = malloc(12);
    Ten="1";
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        strcat(Ten,"0");

    printf("%s",Ten);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yep, why do you think string constants are called string **constants?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ten` is a string literal and you cannot modify it. Try with array instead

```
char Ten[12] = "1";
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    strcat(Ten,"0");

printf("%s",Ten);
```

notice that I created an array of `12` characters, because there should be room for a termination `'\0'`.

You actually don't need `strcat` here, it's just do this

```
char Ten = malloc(12);
if (Ten != NULL)
{
    Ten[0] = '1';
    for (i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++)
        Ten[i] = '0';
    Ten[11] = '\0';
    /* Use Ten here, for example printf it. */
    printf("%s",Ten);
    /* You should release memory. */
    free(Ten);
}
```

or

```
char Ten = malloc(12);
if (Ten != NULL)
{
    Ten[0] = '1';
    memset(Ten + 1, '0', 10);
    Ten[11] = '\0';
    /* Use Ten here, for example printf it. */
    printf("%s",Ten);
    /* You should release memory. */
    free(Ten);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my Post. Now I'm using malloc to set the size of Ten. but still it is not working, why?

Comment: I mean my own code not yours in my first post. look at it. If I compile it it will wait some seconds and then the app will close without showing the result :(

Comment: @Stranger Because assignment doesn't work as you think, `Ten = malloc(12);` if `malloc` succeeded then `Ten` is pointing to a valid addres in memory, if you do `Ten = "1";` now `Ten` is pointng to a read only address and you've lost reference to the writable one returned by `malloc`. I will fix my answer's second part.

Comment: thanks and if you can please check that code via E-Mail ;) Another thing, How to empty the char Ten = malloc(12) ? I need the 12 char string but I need it yo make it empty several times in a loop...

Comment: what you mean `epmty`? set all values to `0` or to `'0'`?, what you should do is call `free()`.

Comment: and as the last question here is this work instead of strcat? "memmove(Ten + 1, "0", 1);"

Comment: no, bad idea... why do you insist on using `strcat`? you could use `memset`.

Comment: @Stranger and format your code better and I might take a look, but as it is I don't want to because it's very hard to read it, avoid oneliners and be consistent with indetantion, and use more whitespace, the compiler ignores them, but the human appriciates them.

Comment: OK thank you, excuse me can I ask this too? why it is not working? (char *num="1"; if (num=="1") DO;) The Do command should work but it is not :(

Comment: It should not work, i told you, you are not assigning the content of `"1"` but i'ts address in memory, test this `"1" != "1"` and it should return `true`, because the addresses will not be equal, each one will live in a different place in memory. If you want to compare two strings, you need `strcmp`. In c++ you can overload the `==` operator that's why `num == "1"` could work if `num` is of type `std::string` because there will be an `std::string::operator==(const &...)` implementation, but `"1" == "1"` will be `false` in c++ too.

Answer (score 5):

You declare `Ten` as a pointer to a string literal. However, you cannot rely on being able to modify a string literal, and thus the program crashes.

To fix this, you can declare `Ten` as an array instead:

```
int main()
{
    char Ten[12]="1"; int i=0;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        strcat(Ten,"0");

    printf("%s",Ten);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you need 12 bytes; 11 for the characters and one for the terminating `NUL` character.

Comment: char Ten[10+1] should suffice.

Comment: @iharob 11 times the `1` plus the terminating NUL.

Comment: Because `"1"` is two bytes, plus one byte concatenated for each loop iteration.

Comment: @Rush nope. The array has "1" in it; then you concatenate a character 10 times, that's 11 characters; plus the terminating NUL, that's 12.

Answer (score 2):

To quote from [strcat manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) on linux:

> The  strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string,
>   overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and
>   then adds a terminating null byte.  The strings may not overlap, and
>   **the dest string must have enough space for the result.**  If dest is not
>   large enough, program behavior  is  unpredictable; buffer overruns are
>   a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

Your `Ten` array is only long enough to store original literal. You need to preallocate memory as long as final desired string.

Comment: It is only big enough for the original literal **and writing is UB**.

Answer (score 1):

String literals might be stored in read only section of memory. Any attempt to modify such a literal causes **undefined behavior**.

To concatenate two strings, the destination must have enough space allocated for the characters to be added and space for `'\0'`. Change the declaration of `Ten` to

```
char Ten[12] = "1";
```

and it will work.

Comment: They are not necessarily stored in read only memory.  In fact, some systems do not even have read only memory.

Comment: ugh, now it's even worse. 3 characters for storing 12?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant; What??

Comment: @haccks: You need room for the original "1", the 10 "0" he wants to append, and the terminating null.

Comment: @haccks you declare an array of 3 characters. The code in question runs `strcat()` on the array 10 times, which results in it having 11 textual characters plus the terminating NUL which is 12. With your declaration, on the 2nd iteration, indexing out-of-bounds will happen.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant; Oops! I missed that loop.

Comment: @Deduplicator; Yes. Agreed.